# Unable to autoplay and loop a cinemagraph from Imgur

Tags: html, embed

I've tried a number of different codes but they don't seem to work. This is my current one, and although it loads fine, it doesn't autoplay or loop, and if I hit play, it would either not loop, or would stop as soon as I scroll down.

```
[video src="https://i.imgur.com/tySpals.mp4" autoplay="on" loop="on" preload="auto"][/video]
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: works for me in WP5 +

Comment: Many browsers do not support autoplaying video.